# How to shift left one specific bit?

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

I want to shift left only one bit in a specific place leaving its position `0`, so I do not want to shift the whole variable with `<<` operator, here is an example: say the variable has the value `1100 1010` and I want to shift the fourth bit then the result should be `1101 0010`.

Comment: If you had `1101 1010` and shifted one at position 4, do you want `1111 0010`?

Comment: So you want to check if 4th bit is set, and then clear 4th bit and set 5th bit?

Comment: @NathanOliver  No the result of your example should be `1101 0010`

Comment: @Drifter OK.  What if you have `1101 0010` and shift the bit at position 4.  Do you want it to be `1100 0010`?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes the story is only shifting one bit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Steps to get there.

1. Pull out bit value from the original number.
2. Left shift the bit value by one.
3. Merge the bit-shifted value back to the original number.

```
// Assuming C++14 or later to be able to use the binary literal integers
int a = 0b11001010;  
int t = a & 0b00001000;  // Pull out the 4-th bit.
t <<= 1;                 // Left shift the 4-th bit.
a = a & 0b11100111;      // Clear the 4-th and the 5-th bit
a |= t;                  // Merge the left-shifted 4-th bit.
```

Comment: Ooh clever to clear both bits and then you don't need to worry about which way you're setting the 5th bit. I like it.

Comment: But to be clear the OP can use this solution even without C++14, correct? That is only needed to set up your example, correct?

Answer (score 4):

For C++, I'd just use a [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset).  Since you set the bit of `pos + 1` to the value of the bit at `pos`, and then set the bit at `pos` to `0` this translate into `bitset` code that is quite easy to read.  That would give you a function like

```
unsigned char shift_bit_bitset(unsigned char val, unsigned pos)
{
    std::bitset<8> new_val(val);
    new_val[pos + 1] = new_val[pos];
    new_val[pos] = 0;
    return new_val.to_ulong();
}
```

Comment: The only thing is what happens if the OP puts in a number greater than 8? Would that overrun a buffer inside `std::bitset`?

Comment: @Chipster It would, but that would happen with any solution though.  If they want safety they can add a check

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the shortest/cleanest way, but this'll do it:

```
unsigned shift_bit = 4;
unsigned char val = 0xCA; // 1100 1010

unsigned char bit_val = val & (1 << shift_bit - 1); // Get current bit value
val = val & ~(1 << shift_bit - 1);                  // Clear initial bit location
val = bit_val ?                                     // Update next bit to 0 or 1
        val | (1 << shift_bit) : 
        val & ~(1 << shift_bit);
```

See it work with the test cases specified in your question and comments here: [ideone](https://ideone.com/d7wZZ7)

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way is

```
(x & 0b11101111) + (x & 0b00001000)
```

that is, clear the bit that will be shifted into and add the bit to be shifted, which will overflow to the left if it is 1.