# Changing 4 bits in a number with a given shift

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I have a decimal number that I need to manipulate 4 bits in with a given shift.
For example, if the number is 208, or 11010000 binary, and I want to change 4 bits to 1101 with a shift of 2. The new number will be 244.
When the change was: 11**1101**00.
Here's my code:

```
void change_bit(int num, int bit, int shift)
{
    num = (num & (0xfffffff0<<shift)) | (bit << shift);
    printf("%d\n", num);
}
```

The shifting of 0xfffffff0 just adds '0' to the left size.
How can I fix it?

Comment: I think this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58598302/how-to-shift-left-one-specific-bit

Comment: These are unsigned positive numbers. How would shifting `11010000` anywhere append ones and end up as 11110100? Arithmetic shifts only apply to signed negative numbers and this isn't it. I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: If you want to change 4 bits then you need `~(0xf << shift)` for the mask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easier if you split complex expressions into smaller bits. It does not affect the efficiency of the code but it will be much easier for you read and understand.

```
unsigned change_bit(unsigned num, unsigned bit, int shift)
{
    unsigned mask = ((1U << 4) - 1) << shift;  // mask to reset the bits at the position

    num &= ~mask;  //reset the bits
    num |= bit << shift;  //set the bits
    return num;
}
```

or more generally

```
unsigned change_bit(unsigned num, unsigned newval, int shift, int numbits)
{
    unsigned mask = ((1 << numbits) - 1) << shift;

    num &= ~mask;
    num |= newval << shift;
    return num;
}
```

and some test code:

```
void print(unsigned val)
{
    for(unsigned x = 1U << 31; x ; x >>= 1)
    {
        printf("%d", !!(val & x));
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    print(208);
    print(change_bit(208, 0b1101, 2));
    printf("%d\n", change_bit(208, 0b1101, 2));
}
```

You should also add some parameters checks.